# Codeigniter Failed to Upload Photo as Medium Blob into Database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I had try to search around the workaround for codeigniter to upload the photo into database function. Everytime i try to submit, it was failed and no upload data was found.

My View :

```
 <?php $attributes = array("id" => "updateMemberPhoto");
                echo form_open_multipart("/Members/updateMemberPhoto", $attributes);?>
                <?php
                echo "<div class='error_msg'> <span class='text-danger'>";

                echo "</span></div>";
                ?>
                 <input type="file" id="imgProfile" name="imgProfile">
                <!-- /.form group -->
                <?php
                if (!empty($customerPhotoForm)) {
                    foreach($customerPhotoForm as $row1) {
                        echo $row1['patientPhotoEditForm'];
                    }
                }
                ?>
                <!-- /.form group -->
                <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

My Controller :

```
  $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
       $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
       $config['max_size']  = '100';
       $config['max_width'] = '1024';
       $config['max_height'] = '768';

       $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if(!$this->upload->do_upload('imgProfile'))
        {
          echo "Failed";
         }else
         {
           $image_file = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
           $img_name=file_get_contents($image_file); /* This function move to image in your database*/
           $this->Member_Model->updateMemberPhoto($img_name);// pass image as parameter to your model
         }
```

MY Model :

```
//Update Member Photo
public function updateMemberPhoto($imgdata){
   $imgdata = file_get_contents($imgdata['full_path']);//get the content
   echo $imgdata;
}
```

I know it was an bad idea to save photo as blob into database, but my customer had already done that with exe function. I'm trying to convert them into web based on codeigniter but i could not upload the photo and save them into blob in database. Is there any function i missout?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you double call function `file_get_contents()` ?

Comment: @Doelmi trying to test out the file path. Do you have solution on this?